# How do I reset the EVs gained for a Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

Other generations of Pokemon, such as X & Y, had ways to lower or even reset specific EV values when EV training Pokemon.

In Sun & Moon, what options do I have in order to EV train my Pokemon from scratch, or even a Pokemon I received via a trade?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Option 1: The 'Reset Berries' are back in this generation, they are acquirable from Berry piles, or from [PokePelago](http://www.serebii.net/sunmoon/pokepelago.shtml). There is a berry for each stat, and they all lower EV by 10 points.

- HP: [Pomeg](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pomeg_Berry)
- Attack: [Kelpsy](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Kelpsy_Berry)
- Defense: [Qualot](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Qualot_Berry)
- Special Attack: [Hondew](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Hondew_Berry)
- Special Defense: [Grepa](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Grepa_Berry)
- Speed: [Tamato](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Tamato_Berry)

Option 2: New to S&M, you can get 'Reset Meals' from the [Festival Plaza](http://www.serebii.net/sunmoon/festivalplaza.shtml). I'm unsure what Plaza level is required for them to start appearing.

Sadly, there is no known equivalent to the 'Reset bag' from XY/ORAS as of yet.